# Please help me. how to handle this error. when i run my application on another computer i get this message:

Tags: vb.net, deployment

In my application I use crystal report version 13. When I install my setup on another computer (just windows xp without any application)it succeeds, but when I run my application, it shows a message like this:

> WindowsApplication1 has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience. If you were in the middle of something, the information you were working on might be lost.

It has what data does this error report contain link. From this link I have collected the  following information.

> Error signature
>
> EventType : clr20r3 P1 : windowsapplication1.exe P2 : 1.0.0.0
>
> P3 : 4ca21bfa P4 : system.windows.forms P5 : 2.0.0.0 P6 : 471ebf68
> P7 : 3dad P8: 97 P9 : systemio.filenotfoundexception

Reporting details :

> This error report includes : information regarding the condition of WindowsApplication1 when the problem occurred the operating system version and computer hardware is use; your Digital Product ID, which could be used to identify your license; and the Internet Protocol(IP) anddress of your computer.
>
> We do not intentionally collect your files, name, address, e-mail address or any other form of personally identifiable information. However the error report could contain customer-specific information such as data from open files. While the information could potentially be used to determine your identity, if present, it will not be used.
>
> The data that we collect will only be used to fix the problem. If more information is available, we will tell you when you report the problem. This error will be sent using a secure connection to a database with limited access and will not be used for marketing purposes.

Comment: "File not found exception" -- can you run your application under a debugger and discover what file it was trying to access?

Answer (score 1):

File not found, that means your application is unable to find the specified file in the location defined internally; that is incorrect path. Check the report file path in your windowsapplication1.exe and where it is residing after installation of your program. It might be a problem.

Comment: but after i check my report path, i could't find any error because where i run my application on computer that have vb 2010 it ok. and when i run my application in another computer without vb 2010 i found error like that. any idea?

Comment: are you trying to run your compiled application or you have moved your project to another computer ? If you have moved your whole project then check for crystal report ref. and try to run under debugger and if it is just a installation package then check for all files in application folder. You may find out your problem, good luck